# How can i edit line 2 in filereader and buffered reader - Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have this code but when i press the button its edit only the first line in txt file:

```
String editN = jTextField13.getText();

if (jTextField18.getText().equals("1")) {
    try {
        String verify, putData;
        File file = new File("Name.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(editN);

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((verify = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (verify != null) {
                putData = verify.replaceAll("here", "there");
                bw.write(putData);
            }
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();

        FileReader fr2 = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fr2);
        String line1 = br2.readLine();
        br2.close();
        Worker1.setText("1. " + line1);

        EditWorker.setVisible(false);
        Workers.setVisible(true);
        Workers.pack();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I need to add that it will edit second line?
I need to edit something that it will edit the second line in the txt file.

Comment: youll get more responses if you add a language tag

Comment: Even if you need to sacrifice one existing tag, listen to patricks advice.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to write some text to a file, read the file, do your replacements, then write a **second** line to the file containing the replaced text?. So in the end you have two lines, the first is the original text and the next one is the text above but with `here` replaced by `there`?